# Rspec let variable in before block not changing between examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In rspec 3.2, I have something based on the following pseudocode:

```
context 'my test context' do
  before do
    method_that_uses(error_message)
  end

  subject { post :my_action, params: a_bunch_of_params }

  let(:error_message) { 'error' }

  it { is_expected.to raise_error(MyException) }

  let(:error_message) { 'different error' }

  it { is_expected.to redirect_to(a_path) }

  let(:error_message) { 'third error' }

  it { is_expected.to redirect_to(another_path) }
end
```

Every example runs with `error_message` set to `third error`. I confirmed this by running pry from the before hook as well. How can I get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because internally, `let` uses [define_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) as seen in the [source for let](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb#L284). You can create a quick example

```
class A
  def create_method(name, &block)
    self.class.send(:define_method, name, &block)
  end
end

a = A.new
a.create_method(:foo) { puts "bar" }
a.create_method(:foo) { puts "baz" }
a.foo
```

and run that and you would see that `define_method` overrides the previous method with the new one. So in your example, you are creating a method and then overriding it's definition twice before you ever get a chance to call it.

You are wanting to run each `error_message` in it's own context like this:

```
def method_that_uses(e)
  puts "running with: #{e}"
end

context 'my test context' do
  before do
    method_that_uses(error_message)
  end

  context 'error' do
    let(:error_message) { 'error' }

    it { puts "run one" }
  end

  context 'second error' do
    let(:error_message) { 'different error' }

    it { puts "run two" }
  end

  context' third error' do
    let(:error_message) { 'third error' }

    it { puts "run three" }
  end
end
```

which, when run, outputs

```
running with: error
run one
.running with: different error
run two
.running with: third error
run three
.
```

This works because `describe` and `context` blocks create a new `ExampleGroup` ([source](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core#basic-structure)) and [ExampleGroup](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb) states

> Example group bodies (e.g. `describe` or `context` blocks) are evaluated in the context of a new subclass of ExampleGroup.

So, `let(:error_message)` is now defining those methods on different subclasses.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a ton. I guess in the future I should just dive into the source. Regardless I understand the cause perfectly now.